# How to get bounding box coordinates around entire text?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL to draw an image and write text on it. After this, I want to draw and get bounding boxes coordinates `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]` for the text on the image. How can I do this ? See below:

```
from IPython.display import Image 
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

# Colour Codes
colours = {"black":(0,0,0),
           "white": (255,255,255)
           }

# Image Description
canvas_width = 200
canvas_height = 200
img_center = (canvas_width/2, canvas_height/2)

# Text Description
size = 50
text = "Text"
font = fonts[2]
font = ImageFont.truetype(font, size)

# File Description
image_name = text

# Generate data:

## Create image canvas
img=Image.new("RGBA", (canvas_width,canvas_height), colours["black"])
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

## Add text on canvas
draw.text(img_center, text, colours["white"], font=font, anchor="mm")

## Draw Bounding Box on Text
draw.rectangle(font.getbbox(text))
print("Text at:", font.getbbox(text))

# Display Image
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
display(img)

# Save Image
# img.save(image_name+".png")
print("Image Saved as: ", image_name+".png")
```

Current output:

[image]

Comment: It does not have to be character-wise, rather, the entire word.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the bounding box of the text w.r.t. its location in the image, you need to call [`getbbox`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getbbox) on `img`, not `font`. Nevertheless, doing so will give unwanted behaviour also:

```
Text at:  (0, 0, 200, 200)
```

That's because you initialize a `RGBA` image without actually using the alpha channel. Thus, the alpha channel is `255` for all pixels, such that ["the bounding box of the ***non-zero regions*** in the image"](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getbbox) is just the full image. So, if there's no actual need for an alpha channel, simply initialize a `RGB` image.

I shortened your code and applied the stated modifications:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# Image
canvas_width = 200
canvas_height = 200
img_center = (canvas_width/2, canvas_height/2)
img = Image.new('RGB', (canvas_width, canvas_height), (0, 0, 0))

# Drawing
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 50)
draw.text(img_center, 'Text', (255, 255, 255), font=font, anchor='mm')
draw.rectangle(img.getbbox())
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

print('Text at: ', img.getbbox())
```

Print output:

```
Text at:  (52, 82, 150, 119)
```

Image output:

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
Pillow:        8.1.0
```

Comment: That `anchor="mm"` is magical, didn't even know it existed. Thanks for sharing!